# how do deal with special characters in html

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, feedparser

I am reading in some xml data and in particular I have the following string

```
H.P. Dembinski, B. K\'{e}gl, I.C. Mari\c{s}, M. Roth, D. Veberi\v{c}
```

this is latex notation. I am using mathjax, but without the $ sign mathjax does not recognize this text. So this text is shown in my browser as printed above. 
I am reading in xml data with the following code

```
today = some date
base_url = "http://export.arxiv.org/oai2?verb=ListRecords&"
url = (base_url + "from=%s&until=%s&" % (today, today) + "metadataPrefix=arXivRaw")

try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)

except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    return

rawdata = response.read()
root = ET.fromstring(rawdata)

if root.find(OAI+'ListRecords') is not None:
   for record in root.find(OAI+'ListRecords').findall(OAI+"record"):
     author_string = info.find(ARXIVRAW+"authors").text
```

I can read the same text using feedparser and in that case I get

```
u'H. P. Dembinski, B. K\xe9gl, I. C. Mari\u015f, M. Roth, D. Veberi\u010d'
```

which my browser can correctly interpret with all the special characters. Here is my feedparser solution

```
url = 'some url'
response = urllib.urlopen(url).read().decode('latin-1')

feed = feedparser.parse(response)

for entry in feed.entries:
    data = {}

    try:
        data['authors'] = ', '.join(author.name for author in entry.authors)
    except AttributeError:
        data['authors'] = ''
```

how do I have to change my ElementTree solution (the first one) to get the same string as from the feedparser solution?

EDIT: Here is a working piece of code which produces the unwanted result

```
import urllib2
from itertools import ifilter
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import feedparser

OAI = "{http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/}"
ARXIV = "{http://arxiv.org/OAI/arXiv/}"
ARXIVRAW = "{http://arxiv.org/OAI/arXivRaw/}"

def main():

     url = "http://export.arxiv.org/oai2?verb=GetRecord&identifier=oai:arXiv.org:1503.09027&metadataPrefix=arXivRaw"

    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(url)

    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        return

    rawdata = response.read().decode('latin-1')
    root = ET.fromstring(rawdata)

    record = root.find(OAI+'GetRecord').findall(OAI+"record")
    meta = record[0].find(OAI+'metadata')
    info = meta.find(ARXIVRAW+"arXivRaw")
    print "author = ", info.find(ARXIVRAW+"authors").text  

    base_url = 'http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?'

    search_query = 'id:1503.09027'              
    max_results = 2000
    sortBy = 'submittedDate'
    sortOrder = 'ascending'

    query = 'search_query=%s&max_results=%i&sortBy=%s&sortOrder=%s' % (search_query, max_results, sortBy, sortOrder)

    response = urllib2.urlopen(base_url+query).read().decode('latin-1')
    feed = feedparser.parse(response)

    for entry in feed.entries:
        print "entry.authors = ", entry.authors

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

output:
python test.py

author =  H.P. Dembinski, B. K\'{e}gl, I.C. Mari\c{s}, M. Roth, D. Veberi\v{c}

Comment: Can you post a usable snippet of the xml (i.e. that could be parsed by ET), with some matching and runnable code that parses this xml produces your top (unwanted) output?

Comment: I added the snipped above

Comment: I think you are using a different url for the feedreader example - when I run your feedreader code with the url you give above in your ET-based code, it doesn't work, there are no entries. Can you post the feedreader code which produces the desired result (printed to stdout)?

Comment: not sure what is going on? when I copy the code above I get the output as shown above

Comment: Yes ET code produces the 'bad' output at the very top. What I am asking is: can you also post working feedreader code which produces the 'good' output, because AFAICT the feedreader snippet you have above doesn't include a URL and doesn't work on the URL in your ET code. If the feedreader 'good' output is coming from different URL/xml data then then your problem changes from 'ET gives different output compared to feedreader from the same URL' (which is how I read your question) to 'ET gives this output from this url and feedreader gives different output from a different url' which is a meh

Comment: ok I extended the code above to also include the feedparser solution. And yes the source is different... I sort of thought the database behind the sources is the same and therefore the data is the same, but if that assumption is wrong I guess I can't get what I want using the ET code. is there any way to detect the latex notation and replace it with the browser understandable notation?

Comment: The feed is only xml, you can parse it with ET. Or use the feedreader solution.

Comment: how can I parse it with ET? ET.parse results in an error?

Comment: I give up. The target moving is.